# How to ignore html if data is empty in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-blade

I am trying to retrieve data from database and check if the data is empty or not. What problem I am facing is that html is showing even if the data is empty. I want to ignore the html tag like example ul li. Here how i tried is like

```
@if(!empty($jobseekers->skill_1))
   <li> My Skill is : {{ \App\skill::where('id',$jobseekers->skill_1)->pluck('name')->first() }}</li><br/>
@endif
```

I want to ignore "My Skill is " if the data is empty. I don't want to show anything.

Comment: What is the value of `$jobseekers->skill_1`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `->get()` you can't simply use any of the below:

```
if (empty($jobseekers->skill_1)) { }

if (!$jobseekers->skill_1) { }

if ($jobseekers->skill_1) { }
```

But, When you are getting data with `first()` method, You can simply use all above methods.

Because if you `dd($jobseekers->skill_1);` you'll notice an instance of `Illuminate\Support\Collection` is always returned, even when there are no results.

I think you are using `!empty()` on data with `->get()` method which will always return true even data is empty. You need to use other way.

To determine if there are any results you can do any of the following:

```
if (!$jobseekers->skill_1->isEmpty()) { }

if ($jobseekers->skill_1->count()) { }

if (count($jobseekers->skill_1)) { }
```

Comment: Glad to see and congrats

Answer (score 1):

If you get $jobseekers with `get()` method you can not use `empty($jobseekers )`

instead of empty you can use other conditions :

```
@if($jobseekers->skill_1 != '')
```

in this condition you check skill_1 as empty string

also

```
@if($jobseekers->skill_1)
```

and etc

replace your code with below code and check it:

```
@if($jobseekers->skill_1 != '')
   <li> My Skill is : {{ \App\skill::where('id',$jobseekers->skill_1)-pluck('name')->first() }}</li><br/>
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use **isset()**

```
@if(isset($jobseekers->skill_1))
    <li> My Skill is : {{ \App\skill::where('id',$jobseekers->skill_1)->pluck('name')->first() }}</li><br/>
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

**you can use count method**

```
 @if(count($jobseekers->skill_1)>0)
       <li> My Skill is : {{ \App\skill::where('id',$jobseekers->skill_1)-pluck('name')->first() }}</li><br/>
    @endif
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@if(count($data)>0)
 //write your code which you want to show if data is available
@endif
```